# Using setters on custom controltemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a resource dictionary file in which I have a custom ControlTemplate definition

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"
             TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
   ....
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

(Taken from here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the dictionary file file contains the entire thing))

I use it to change the looks of the control a bit. But now, I want to be able to dynamically change the width of it with setters.

But the problem is, if I for example do this (in another res. dictionary file)

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">               
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
</Style>
```

It completely overrides my custom ControlTemplate and it uses the default system combobox, where it applies that width.
But I want that setter to apply the  width to my custom ControlTemplate  instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing style in a resource it will always overwrite to default behavior
If you want it to inherit some other style you need to use `BasedOn` property:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}">               
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: It says "cannot find resource"

Comment: My bad over here, didn't notice ComboBoxToggleButton is a ControlTemplate and not a Style. Anyhow, does your control have Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"? Because your code is working for me

Comment: You mean the < combobox..> itself? No, I globally skin all comboboxes with TargetType="ComboBox" so that I don't have to have lot's of extra code in each combobox. Do I need to add it in order for it to work?

Comment: It's the code from that link I posted, I simply placed it into a resource dictionary file, which I then include into my window.xaml files and it automatically affects all comboboxes

Comment: _which I then include into my window.xaml files_. How?

Comment: the standard way:     < Window.Resources>                   
        < ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Style.xaml" />                                   
    < /Window.Resources>

Comment: Ok I've found the problem (I don't know why it didn't work at first for me but w/e). In your Resource Dictionary you have <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" you need to change that to some meaningful key like  <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle". Then you can use BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" and it should work